# Replace period with colon after year with biblatex to approximate ametsoc guidelines

Tags: biblatex

I'm using `authoryear` with some customisations to give me a bibliography entry like this:

> Gal-Chen, T. and R. C. Somerville, 1975. On the Use of a Coordinate
>   Transformation for the Solution of the Navier-Stokes Equations. J.
>   Comp. Phys., **17**, 209–228.

In my LaTeX file I use:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear,
  firstinits=true,
  doi=false,
  isbn=false,
  uniquename=init]{biblatex}
```

And I define a `biblatex.cfg` file in the same directory:

```
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{number}%
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1},}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\textbf{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1\isdot}
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}
```

How can I change the period to a colon after the year of publication?

Comment: You say you did some customizations; please, make a full example.

Comment: If you have not changed too much `\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}` should do it. But we really need an MWE to see whether this can help here.